# How to turn a path with straight lines into a curved path automatically in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, adobe-fireworks, cs6, automation

I know how to do this manually, but I need an automatic way (either a script or just a command in Illustrator).

Here's a line like the one I mean. Notice how it's all made of straight lines (The blue dots are the anchor points):

[image]

**How can I turn this into a true curve easily?**

Note that I have all of Adobe Creative Cloud at my disposal, so if there is a tool in Fireworks, Photoshop, or anything else that can help, it is still relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try `Object > Path > Simplify` and adjust the *Curve Precision* and *Angle Threshold* settings to perhaps get a curve.

There's no straightforward method, which I'm aware of, other than this.

Comment: Worked great! It actually did just what I wanted.

Comment: Many times, if you don't have an actual distinctive curve in your straight-lined path, this method won't work so well. For instance, using a path more like what @user56reinstatemonica8 wrote below this wouldn't work.

Comment: I never posted this solution works for *every* possible situation. It merely works for *this* situation. The down vote was, well, a bit unwarranted in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

There's also the [`Smooth tool`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6246a.html#WSCB13EA3D-2DAE-4a05-BB60-0FCA9907DDA9a) [image] if you prefer a more hands-on approach. Rub it over a selected path, and it smooths it where you rub. If it doesn't smooth enough, keep rubbing.

[From this tutorial:](http://www.bittbox.com/illustrator/how-to-make-smooth-lines-in-illustrator)

[image]

[image]

Double-click the tool icon to set how closely the smoothed line sticks to the original (`fidelity`) and how strong the smoothing is each time (`smoothness`).

---

A nice additional feature of the smooth tool is, it only applies to paths and **points that are selected**. So, if there are parts of a path you want to stay exactly how they are, and parts you want smoothed, you can select just the points you want to be smoothed  then use the smooth tool.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to Illustrator. I've been using the **Direct Selection Tool (A)** & **Delete Anchor Point Tool (-)** to clean up huge, complex traces. It's been taking forever, so this is such a relief.

Answer (score 3):

Select the path that you want to convert and with the direct selection tool and the shift key pressed, exclude one point. Some new buttons appear under the menu, one of them is to convert selected anchor points from corner to smooth.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer! I believe with many different paths, for example drawing a map with roads, this is the best method. It's the quickest and most efficient, you don't need to switch from the pen tool to another tool (smooth tool) and once you get the hang of it on which nodes to click, it gives almost perfect results.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done Effect > Stylize > Round Corners. Then go Object > Expand appearance to create a curved line that is editable with handles.

Answer (score -2):

Effect > Stylize > Round Corners.

Comment: This will not turn the lines into a single path, it will just round out the edges.